# Get website's network data with Java

Tags: java, google-chrome, web-inspector

I have been looking entire day for any kind of library or information for Java which would allow me to get networks data from the chrome's inspect element.

I came accross JTidy, HtmlUnit and many others, but none of them had any information about that.

My task is to make Java app which would go to the website, presses the button and gets the networks data after this button is pressed.

**Is it possible to achieve it or I should forget about it?**

Comment: What do you mean, " gets the networks data?"

Comment: Well when you open websites inspector it shows all of the content which website received. Like images, js, media etc. And if you were to start listening to the song it will appear on it with the url for the song as well

Comment: You mean you want to crawl websites?

Comment: @Kayaman Dont know what you actually mean by that, but thats why I would like to get this implemented: I would like to get the direct url of the song from the website so it could play randomly in the morning as my alarm clock.

Comment: @StuckBetweenTrees You can use JSoup to do that. You can parse the tags and look for the button and then click the button to load a new page. Again get the info using JSoup. I recently did something like that for my project using JSoup.

Comment: Yes, I used this for takinf data from the website but I did not found any info of how to use for inspect element

Comment: @StuckBetweenTrees Inspect element is a feature of the browser. It doesn't exist outside the context of the browser, so what you're asking doesn't really make sense in the way you put it. You can of course examine web page contents programmatically, and you're probably looking after some sort of crawler functionality.

Comment: @Kayaman Well, I mean once I press on the link and it starts displaying inside networks tab in the inspect elements, cant we catch the same link with the java code and display in the console or smth?

Comment: Of course you can program a similar functionality in Java. You just can't use the one that's included with the browser. If you haven't worked with networking before or don't understand how HTTP works, you'll probably need to do some reading first. There's plenty of libraries to choose from.

Comment: Well I just came across the different way of how to get around this problem. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Hi, did you find solution?

Comment: I did by scrapping the data using jsoup.org. I cant remember exactly but I did used jsoup.org for sure